# How to start a process in a given container? (how to start acrobate reader in a groupbox?) in VB.Net

Tags: process, containers, preview, parents

I would like to have a preview of pdf and xps files displayed in my application. So I would like to be able to run a process and give it the "location" or the container where it should run from.
Is there anyway to do that?
I presently can launch whatever application I want, with the necessary ProcessStartInfo to open the file, but I would need the application to be contained within a particular control, rather than being a standalone application.
I didn't find a .Parent property for example, that would allow me to do it.
If you have an idea, let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some findings:

first here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/148658-embedding-another-program-into-app/

first solution: use a webbrowser control with:

```
  WebBrowser1.Url = New System.Uri("file://" & myFileNameHere)
```

Second solution (found here: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1598720 )

```
Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = 274
Private Const SC_MAXIMIZE As Integer = 61488
Declare Auto Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As Integer
Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer

 Private Sub Test3()
Try
        myProcess.Kill()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim ii As Integer = 33
    End Try

    Dim valueFileName As String = myFileNameHere 
    Dim myProcessInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    myProcessInfo.FileName = myCompletePathToTheEXEFileHere
    myProcessInfo.WorkingDirectory = valueFileName.Substring(0, valueFileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
    myProcessInfo.Arguments = valueFileName.Substring(valueFileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)
    myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessInfo
    myProcess.Start()
    myProcess.WaitForInputIdle()
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    SetParent(myProcess.MainWindowHandle, Me.GroupBox1.Handle)
    SendMessage(myProcess.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0)
```

The code above, is working and could probably be improved.
I'm stilling working on it!

Comment: Interesting question, interesting answer! I've seen stuff like this before for rehosting Word etc within an application, never known how it's done until now :)

Comment: The webBrowser control is actually quite powerfull: it's opening a lot of files (.doc, .xls,.csv,.ppt,.xps,.pdf, etc.)

Comment: One problem I found with the WebBrowser control: you need to think of killing the process that it opened for each particular file. So you might want to add some code like the one found here: http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/538885-webbrowser-excel-processs-till-running, or simply by counting your process BEFORE and AFTER the document is opened, then kill the extra one each time you open a new document and when you dispose of the control.